# Infragistics Grid disappears when grid parent element is expanded/collapsed using JavaScript style.display property

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

Infragistics Grid disappears when grid parent element is expanded/collapsed using JavaScript style.display property. When I expand the parent element the area covered by grid is blank. If I change any of the style of any child control from IE Developer toolbar, the grid becomes visible. This behaviour is specific to IE. I check in IE8 with and without compatibility mode. Same is working fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution from http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/rpfloat.html. Basically, I flip zoom property of document.forms[0] to 0 and 1 alternatively which will update the layout of the page.